# Cannot load router interface in Win8.1, even though ip address, DNS, etc all set correctly

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dns, wireless-router

Win8.1 continually frustrates me.  I need help to access my router's web interface.

OK, my web interface is 192.168.1.1.  This is confirmed with IPCONFIG.  My Internet Protocol v4 and v6 settings are all correct (obtain DNS automatically, and obtain IP address automatically).

My setup is: wife's computer HP Pavilion dv6000 laptop running WinXP, my computer HP Envy m6 running Win8.1.  Modem is Huawei HG659 WIFI router.  We're both using the WiFi link.  My anti-virus is Windows De

In the Wi-Fi Properties box, there are two items that are not checked: Microsoft Network Adapter Multiplexor Protocol, and Microsoft LLDP Protocol Driver.

I can surf the net without problems, download and send emails no problems either.  So why can't I access my router?

Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you tried a wired connection to the router?

Comment: Yep, no difference.

Comment: Next step is probably to reset the router :/

Comment: Tried doing that many times already, it does not change the situation.  Just frustrates the !@#$ out of me.

Comment: According to your router's [manual](http://help.spark.co.nz/euf/assets/images/ibase/modem/HG659/Huawei%20HG659%20-%20Quick%20Start%20Guide.pdf), the default IP is set to 192.168.1.254. Assuming you haven't manually configured a different one, try that IP. This is all assumes you're not confusing 192.168.1.1 as the IP of your machine, not the router's.

Comment: Please add the output from `ipconfig /all` (from a wired connection) to your question. Are you perhaps connected to someone elses wireless connection?

Comment: It's *possible*, however generally unlikely, that your router's web address might be hosted on a different IP than the primary gateway service. Try 192.168.1.254, like @happy_soil suggested. Also, have you tried both http:// *and* https://? Have you tried using different browsers? Have you tried running those browsers in "Safe Mode" (not Windows' Safe Mode - the browser's Safe Mode, where all plugins are disabled)? What error(s) do you see when trying to navigate to the web interface? Output from `ipconfig -all`, `route print`, and `tracert 8.8.8.8` could be useful.

Comment: Also, until you've established access to the web interface, all troubleshooting should be done via a wired connection with WiFi on the laptop turned off. This eliminates potential interference from two possible issues: 1.) You may be inadvertently to the wrong WiFi network. 2.) Your router may be configured to disallow admin access over WiFi.

Answer (score 0):

most routers use an SSL connection.  have you tried HTTP**S**://[routers ip address]